# Error in points2grid when creating spatial points from CSV of coordinates in R

Tags: r, raster, spatial, read.csv

I am creating a raster in R from a CSV data.frame "df" that contains biweekly temperature values as well as latitude and longitude coordinates.

The data.frame "df" was created in R and saved as a CSV.  When I run the following code with my data.frame already in my R workspace, I do not get any errors.

```
u <- crs(reference_raster)
df <- points
points$x <- points$Lat
points$y <- points$Long
coordinates(points) <- ~y + x
proj4string(points) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
points <- spTransform(pts, crs(u))
gridded(points) = TRUE
```

However, when I use `read.csv` to read in my data.frame "df" into my R workspace, I then get an error

```
suggested tolerance minimum: 0.750246 
Error in points2grid(points, tolerance, round) : 
  dimension 1 : coordinate intervals are not constant
```

Like I mentioned, my code works perfectly if I keep the data.frame in my R workspace from when it was created, but it doesn't work when I read the data.frame back in as a CSV.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I had the same problem, just round the data when importing it. It fixed it for me.